# Alternating group index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am self-studying abstract algebra and Galois theory and I am not sure my understating is correct. I know that the Alternating subgroup $\mathbb{A}_n$ has index $2$ in the symmetric group $\mathbb{S}_n$ (the proof can be found in Herstein or Dummit & Foote).

Does that imply every element $\sigma\in\mathbb{S}_n$ can be expressed as $\sigma=\widetilde{\sigma}\alpha_{\sigma}$ where $\widetilde{\sigma}$ is any chosen fixed element in $\mathbb{S}_n$ and $\alpha_{\sigma}\in\mathbb{A}_n$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $\widetilde{\sigma}\in \mathbb{A}_n$ then clearly $\widetilde{\sigma}\alpha_\sigma\in\mathbb{A}_n$. On the other hand if $\widetilde{\sigma}\not\in \mathbb{A}_n$ then $\widetilde{\sigma}\alpha_\sigma\not\in\mathbb{A}_n$. It is a simple consequence of the fact that cosets partition whole group.

The correct claim is slightly different: if $\widetilde{\sigma}\not\in\mathbb{A}_n$ then every element $\sigma\in\mathbb{S}_n$ is either in $\mathbb{A}_n$ or $\sigma=\widetilde{\sigma}\alpha_\sigma$ for some $\alpha_\sigma\in\mathbb{A}_n$.